# Why does Lang need finite measure support in the proof Lemma 3.2 (Real and Functional Analysis)?

Tags: integration, analysis, lebesgue-integral

If anyone has the book, Lemma 3.2 and its proof are on pages 130-132.

Here is the statement of the lemma:

> Let $\{g_n\}$ and $\{h_n\}$ be Cauchy sequences of step mappings of $X$ into $E$, converging almost everywhere to the same map.  Then the following limits exist and are equal: $$\lim\int_X g_n=\lim\int_X h_n$$ Furthermore, the Cauchy sequences $\{g_n\}$ and $\{h_n\}$ are equivalent, i.e. $\{g_n-h_n\}$ is an $L^1$-null sequence.

For context, $X$ is a measure space, $E$ is a Banach space, and Lang has previously defined a step mapping from $X$ to $E$ as a function that is measurable, has finite image, and whose support has finite measure (this is not Lang's precise definition but an equivalent one).

The proof starts by showing that $\lim\int_X g_n$ (and $\lim\int_X h_n$ exist; once we have done that we can define $f_n=g_n-h_n$, and it only remains to show that $\int_X f_n$ and $\int_X |f_n|$ go to 0, from our knowledge that $f_n\rightarrow 0$ almost everywhere.  It suffices to prove the latter.

Fixing $\epsilon>0$ and choosing $N$ such that the Cauchy condition for $f_n$ holds, we have to show that $\int_X|f_n|$ is arbitrarily small for $n$ arbitrarily great.  To do this, Lang divides $X$ into three parts and bounds the integral on each part.  This is the step that my question is about, because it seems sufficient to just divide $X$ into two parts.

First Lang lets $A\subseteq X$ be a set of finite measure which includes the support of $f_N$.  Then $$\int_{X-A}|f_n|=\int_{X-A}|f_n-f_N|\leq\int_X|f_n-f_N|<\epsilon$$ as long as $n\geq N$.

Then Lang cuts $A$ into two parts, using Lemma 3.1, which I will reproduce the statement of:

> Let $\{f_n\}$ be a Cauchy sequence of step mappings.  Then there exists a subsequence which converges pointwise almost everywhere, and satisfies the additional property: given $\epsilon$ there exists a set $Z$ of measure $<\epsilon$ such that this subsequence converges absolutely and uniformly outside $Z$.

Lang uses this lemma to produce a set $Z\subseteq A$ with measure $< \frac{\epsilon}{1+\|f_N\|}$ (where $\|\cdot\|$ is sup norm) such that $f_n$ has a subsequence which converges absolutely on $A-Z$.  Choosing $Z$ to also include the measure zero set on which $f_n$ doesn't converge to $0$, we see that this subsequence converges absolutely on $A-Z$ to $0$.  Then clearly $\int_{A-Z} |f_n|<\epsilon$ for $n$ great enough in this subsequence, and we are left with the third part, $Z$.

For this, we do $$\int_Z|f_n|\leq \int_Z|f_n-f_N|+\int_Z|f_N|\leq \int_X|f_n-f_N|+\mu(Z)\|f_N\|<2\epsilon$$
which works for $n$ great enough in the subsequence.

A possible objection is that we have not proved that $\int_X|f_n|$ is eventually $<\epsilon$, only that it is frequently $<\epsilon$.  However, the Cauchy condition will show the former from the latter.

My question is, what is the point of $A$?  Why don't we apply Lemma 3.1 directly to $X$ and break $X$ up into $Z$ and $X-Z$?  Apparently Lang would rather work in $A$ because it has finite measure, but I am not sure where he uses this condition in the proof.

Answer (score 1):

I just figured out the answer.  It really helped to write it all out.  To show that $\int_{A-Z}|f_n|<\epsilon$ from the uniform convergence of the subsequence of $f_n$ on $A-Z$, we need the fact that $A-Z$ has finite measure.  Uniform convergence says that we can make the sup norm, not the $L^1$ norm, of $f_n$, as small as we want.  So we make it smaller than $\frac{\epsilon}{\mu(A)}$; then $\int_{A-Z}|f_n|<\epsilon$.

Comment: Thanks for this answer I had the exact same question while reading the proof. I tried to rewrite the proof in details below and I would be very grateful if you could give me some feedback.

Answer (score 0):

For my own understanding I will try to rewrite the proof. In this proof there are three norms at play :

1. The Banach space norm $|\cdot|$ defined for vectors in $E$.
2. The step map seminorm $||\cdot||_1$ defined for step maps $f:X\to E$ by $||f||_1:=\int |f|$
3. The sup norm $||\cdot||$ defined for any map $f:X\to E$ by $||f||:=\sup \{ |f(x)|:x\in X\}$

Now we begin the proof. Let $(g_n),(h_n)$ be Cauchy sequences of step maps with respect to $||\cdot||_1$, both converging almost everywhere to some $f:X\to E$. Using the properties of the integral for step maps we have

$$\bigg|\int g_n -\int g_m\bigg|=\bigg|\int ( g_n-g_m)\bigg|\leq\int |g_n-g_m|=||g_n- g_m||_1\to 0$$

as $n,m\to \infty$. This shows that that $\int g_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in $E$ with respect to $|\cdot|$. Since $E$ is complete, $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int g_n$ exist in $E$. The same argument shows that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int h_n$ also exists in $E$.

Let $f_n=g_n-h_n$ for each $n$. Note that $(f_n)$ is a sequence of step maps which is Cauchy with respect to $||\cdot||_1$ and converges almost everywhere to zero. What remains to be shown is that $\int f_n$ and $\int |f_n|$ both converge to zero, for then $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int g_n=\lim_{n\to\infty} \int h_n$ and $ \lim_{n\to\infty} ||g_n-h_n||_1=0$. Moreover, from the inequality $|\int f_n|\leq \int |f_n|$ it suffices to show $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int |f_n|=0$.

Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given. There exist $N\geq 1 $ such that $m,n\geq N$ implies $||f_n-f_m||_1<\varepsilon$. Since $f_N$ is a step map, there exist a measurable set $A$ of finite measure outside of which $f_N$ vanishes. Then for all $n\geq N$ we have

$$\int_{X\setminus A} |f_n|=\int_{X\setminus A} |f_n-f_N|\leq \int|f_n-f_N|=||f_n-f_N||_1<\epsilon $$

By Lemma 3.1 there exist a measurable set $B$ with $\mu(B)<\frac{\varepsilon}{1+||f_N||}$ and a subsequece $(f_{n_k})$ of $(f_n)$ such that $(f_{n_k})$ converges uniformly on $X\setminus B$. Moreover, there exist a null set $N$ outside of which $(f_n)$ converges to zero pointwise. Let $Z:=B\cup N$. Then it follows that $(f_{n_k})$ converges uniformly to zero on $X\setminus Z$, and in particular on $A\setminus Z$. Hence there exist $N'\geq 1$ such that $k\geq N'$ implies $|f_{n_k}(x)|<\frac{\varepsilon}{1+\mu(A\setminus Z)}$ for all $x\in A\setminus Z$. Then for all $k\geq N'$ we have

$$ \int_{A\setminus Z} |f_{n_k}|\leq \int_{A\setminus Z} \frac{\varepsilon}{1+\mu(A\setminus Z)}=  \frac{\varepsilon \mu(A\setminus Z)}{1+\mu(A\setminus Z)}<\varepsilon$$

If in addition $k$ large enough that $n_k\geq N$, then by the choice of $B$ we also have

$$ \int_Z |f_{n_k}|\leq \int_Z |f_{n_k}-f_N|+\int_Z |f_N|\leq ||f_{n_k}-f_N||_1 +\mu(Z)||f_N||<\varepsilon+\varepsilon=2\varepsilon$$

Putting everything together we obtain that, for $k$ large enough,

$$ ||f_{n_k}||_1= \int |f_{n_k}|=\int_{X\setminus A} |f_{n_k}|+\int_{A\setminus Z} |f_{n_k}|+\int_{A\cap Z} |f_{n_k}|$$

$$\leq \int_{X\setminus A} |f_{n_k}|+\int_{A\setminus Z} |f_{n_k}|+\int_{ Z} |f_{n_k}|$$

$$\leq \varepsilon + \varepsilon + 2\varepsilon = 4\varepsilon $$

As $\varepsilon>0$ is arbitrary, it follows that $||f_{n_k}||_1\to 0$ as $k\to \infty$.

We have shown that, for every $\varepsilon>0$, $||f_{n}||_1<\varepsilon$ for infinitely many $n$. The final step is to show that $||f_{n}||_1\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$. Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given. Since $(f_n)$ is Cauchy with respect to $||\cdot||_1$ there exist $N\geq 1$ such that $||f_n-f_m||_1<\varepsilon/2$ for all $n,m\geq N$. Also, by what we just did there exist $m\geq N$ such that $||f_{m}||_1<\varepsilon/2$. It follows that for all $n\geq N$ we have

$$ ||f_{n}||_1\leq ||f_n-f_m||_1+||f_m||_1<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}=\varepsilon$$

As $\varepsilon>0$ is arbitrary it follows that $||f_{n}||_1\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$.